# Responsive Inline-Block to Block 2nd div extends beyond container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having what appears to be an odd problem and putting this out to see if someone sees something I am not seeing.
There are two left-floated boxes on this page, followed by a clearfix. The question only deals with columns in the left box.
In the left box, I have div rows with two inline-block div columns.
When I change these with a media query, the second column (DI-Right) extends beyond the container (DI_LeftCol).
This is consistent down the column. In other words, DI-Left stays within the container, DI-Right does not, through a number of consecutive rows.

There are no other objects on the page that should affect this, and I have checked through both the original css and responsive css, and there is no other reference to DI-Right or DI-Left.

**Before Media Query**                             **After Media Query**
++++++++++++    ++++++++++++    ++++++++++++
* DI-Left         +     + DI-Right        +    + DI-Left           +
++++++++++++    ++++++++++++    ++++++++++++
                                                             ++++++++++++++++++
                                                             + DI-Right                    +
                                                             ++++++++++++++++++
**HTML** (Wrapped in a PHP echo)

```
echo('
<div id="DI_LeftCol">
    <div class="DivHeadRow">Information</div>
    <div id="DI_LeftColInner">
        <div class="DI-Row">
            <div class="DI-Left">ID #:</div>
            <div class="DI-Right">'.$ID.'</div>
        </div>
        //etc (Several rows)
    </div>
</div>');
```

**CSS**

```
#DI_LeftCol {float:left; width:45%; max-width:400px; margin-bottom:15px; margin-top:30px;}
.DivHeadRow {float:left; width:100%; border:1px solid #949494;}
#DI_LeftColInner {border:1px solid #808080; width:100%; background-color:#F5F5F5;}
#DI_RightCol {width:45%; max-width:500px; float:right; margin:28px 15px 8px 15px; text-align:center;}
.DI-Row {display:block; width:100%;}
.DI-Left {display:inline-block; padding-right:3px; text-align:right; width:120px; min-width:120px; font-weight:600;}
.DI-Right {display:inline-block; padding-left:3px; text-align:left; width:210px; min-width:210px;}
```

**Media Query**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
    #DI_LeftCol .DivHeadRow {float:none; width:100%; border:1px solid #949494;}
    .DI-Row .DI-Left {display:block; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%; font-weight:800; background-color:#CFC9D3;}
    .DI-Row .DI-Right {display:block; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%;}
    .DI-Row .DI-TermLink {display:inline-block; padding-left:3px; text-align:left; width:50px; min-width:50px;}
}
```

Comment: set `min-width` to `auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.DI-Right` has a `min-width:210px` which is not overridden in the media query, that is, it doesn't shrink beneath that value. You have to override the value in the media query with another value (`0` if you don't want any `min-width` at all).

In your media query, something like

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
    #DI_LeftCol .DivHeadRow {float:none; width:100%; border:1px solid #949494;}
    .DI-Row .DI-Left {display:block; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%; font-weight:800; background-color:#CFC9D3;}
    .DI-Row .DI-Right {display:block; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%;min-width:0;}
    .DI-Row .DI-TermLink {display:inline-block; padding-left:3px; text-align:left; width:50px; min-width:50px;}
}
```

Comment: Ha! Silly me! I had tried setting the min-width to 100% and that didn't do it. Never thought about setting it to 0. LOL! Thanks NevNein!